# how to change input type text value after selected dropdown list in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I tried to change the value in the input type text with data from the database after selecting data from the dropdown list

but the data does not enter the text input value

```
<?php
//Include the database configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';

//Fetch all the country data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY country_name ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
<select id="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['country_id'].'">'.$row['country_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>

<div id="state">

</div>


<?php
//Include the database configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';

if(!empty($_POST["country_id"])){
    //Fetch all state data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id = ".$_POST['country_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY state_name LIMIT 1");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //State option list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        $row = $query->row();
        echo '<input type="text" id="state" value="'.$row['state_name'].'">';
    }
}
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country').on('change',function(){
        var countryID = $(this).val();
        if(countryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'index.php',
                data:'country_id='+countryID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#state').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

i expect the output according to data from the database

here is my database :

**database country**

[image: 1]

**database state**

[image: 2]

**error**

[image: 3]

Comment: any error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#state').val(html);
```

or

```
 $('#state').text(html);
```

Comment: it's doesnt work using val; using text displayed a code why ?

Answer (score 0):

To fill an input of type text with some data or string, you have to use the .val() jquery function, not .html() - Replace

```
$('#state').html(html);
```

with

```
$('#state').val(html);
```

Comment: html is supposed to be a variable defined somewhere up in your code. I think you what you are looking for is $('#state').val(countryID);

Answer (score 0):

this below code should work.

```
$('#state').html(html);
```